# What's the grammatical structure of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Does this sentence  "**as were all things Thanos**" means **"as if all things were Thanos**?" If so, is it common **to reverse "were" while omit "if"**? Could anyone help with its grammar or structure?  Greatly appreciated if more examples could be given, many thanks.

Here is the sentence in the context:

> With Spider-Man safely earthbound, Iron Man attached himself to the
>   ship and began using lasers from his gauntlet to cut into the hull. A
>   piece flew out and Tony hoisted himself in. Looking around, it was
>   like nothing he had seen before, yet strangely familiar, **as were all
>   things Thanos**. Ghosts floating in his mind for six years ever since
>   he first made contact during the climax of the Battle of New York.
>   Pressing a button, his boots activated stealth mode and he silently
>   began to examine the invading ship.
>
> the avengers 3

Answer (score 1):

I had to look up ***Thanos*** to understand the usage. For anyone else who doesn't know, he's a [*fictional **supervillain***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos) appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics (hence, a natural enemy of ***superhero*** Spiderman).

Standard English syntax would require an ***adjective / adjectival phrase*** after the noun phrase ***all things***. In a typical context such as [*All things **bright and beautiful***](https://library.timelesstruths.org/music/All_Things_Bright_and_Beautiful/), we can interpret the syntax as a "reduced" version of *All things **which are** bright and beautiful*.

But in OP's context, ***Thanos*** is a ***proper noun***, not an adjective, so it's a slightly stylisted / non-standard construction which we can understand as a reduced version of *all things **concerning** Thanos*. That's to say ***everything to do with Thanos, everything about him*** was simultaneously both "previously unseen" (unfamiliar) ***and*** familiar (it's up to the reader to imagine for himself exactly what that might mean or feel like).

Comment: then why use "as were" in this sentence? is it common to use this way? do you mean "as were" here equals the structure " which are"?

Comment: is "were" here a subjunctive? why not say "as all things were Thanos"

Comment: No. That's just another "stylised" usage, inverting the natural *subject + verb* sequence for English from ***as all things Thanos were*** (where ***were*** is just Simple Past). Compare "stylised" ***He's tired, as are we** [all]* with "standard" ***He's tired, as we** [all] **are.***

Comment: It's ***were*** rather than ***are*** because the context is a ***past tense narrative.*** See immediately preceding *Tony **hoisted** himself in* (not ***hoists***).

Comment: isn't  "so" should be used in your example: "He's tired, so are we all". ? I am so puzzled by the use of "as" here.

Comment: We can use either ***so*** or ***as*** in such constructions. There's a *tiny* difference in "nuance", but it's difficult to explain exactly what that difference is (most native speakers wouldn't be able to), so you probably shouldn't bother about it.